# I cannot get mediaelement.js to playback AACP (AAC Plus) audio

Tags: jwplayer, mediaelement.js, aac

I'm trying to get mediaelement.js to work with an AAC+ (HE-AACv1) audio stream. I verified the stream is working by playing the file back in WinAmp but it will not work with mediaelement.js.

I also tried JW Player with no success. I'm willing to switch to any web player with AAC+ support.

MediaElement.js Code:

```
<audio controls="controls" width="320" height="80">
  <source type="audio/aacp" src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/stream" />
</audio>
```

Firefox complains and displays no player: "Specified "type" attribute of "audio/aacp" is not supported. Load of media resource xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/stream failed.
site.com/
Line 0"

Chrome loads the player and continues to load the stream but never plays the audio.

JW Player code:

```
<script>
jwplayer("container").setup({
flashplayer: "player.swf",
height: "24",
width: "730",
file: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/stream",
controlbar: "bottom",
type: "sound",
bufferlength: "10",
autostart: "true"
});
</script>
```

Nothing plays in either Chrome or Firefox with the JW Player though the player does display.

I can get MediaElement.js and JW Player to work with our MP3 streams but we are looking to move away from MP3.

Demo link: http://www.whro.org/allstreams/compare/

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are trying to use the JW Player?

Comment: The first snippet is not a mediaelement code. It's the HTML audio tag. Can you provide the medialement code?

Comment: I added a demo link in the original post. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I actually can't get this url to load? - http://64.5.130.55:8000/stream, just in browser.

Comment: I've had the ports open on the firewall. I apologize for not having that setup correctly before.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a late response, but maybe it will help someone:

I actually tried faking the type to be audio/aac in the source' type of the audio element (instead of audio/aacp) and it works in a pure html5 solution on the devices that are able to play aac streams 
(read: iPhone (Safari), iPad (safari+Chrome), Blackberry(default browser)).

This works for HE-AACv1 and HE-AACv2 files, but v2 files can sometimes have glitches in the sound.